# Create gForms and consolidate all answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I have to create a survey where I use a multiple choice grid with rows and columns such as:

```
| Item | Rate 1 | Rate 2 | Rate 3 |
| ---- | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| Item1 | x |  |  |
| Item6 |  | x |  |
| Item9 |  | x |  |
```

I need to send the form to 100 users. I need to create a different form for each user because the number of rows (items) will change based on the users. I do NOT want to create a web app with HTML. I would like to use the Google Forms.

I am planning to use this script for each user and modify it to dynamically change the rows based on the user.

```
var form = FormApp.create('Title');
form.setDescription("Please use the following criteria for rating:\n - **1**: explanation..... ");
form.setCollectEmail(true);
var item = form.addGridItem();
item.setTitle('Indicate your rating')
    .setRows(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']) //I will change here and I know how to do it
    .setColumns(['1', '2', '3'])
    .setRequired(true);
var item = form.addParagraphTextItem();
item.setTitle('Provide additional explanation');
```

The issue is that I also need to collect the answers and consolidate them for each item. There will be 100 forms with same columns, but different rows.

How can I access the answer easily? Is there as way to set the form to send the answers to another script/gSheet?

One way to do it is to use the Class FormResponse such as `.getResponse()`. But I would need to run it for each of the created form every x hours to get the latest responses and then consolidate in a Google sheet.

Is there a way to avoid a cron job which keep monitor the answers? For example if I could collect the answers only when the are submitted.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, for example, In the case of Google Forms, the responses of multiple Google Forms can be submitted to each sheet in a single Spreadsheet. I thought that this might be able to be used in your situation. So, how about linking each Google Form with a single Spreadsheet, and using the OnSubmit trigger at Spreadsheet? By this, all response can be retrieved by one script. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation. So, if this was not suitable, I apologize.

Comment: The question has several problems. It needs more more focus, it doesn't include enough details, it doesn't include research efforts.

Comment: "I need to send the form to 100 users. I need to create a different form for each user". Further to @Tanaike. It sounds like you are proposing to create 100 unique forms. Is that right? There is no reason why all the responses can't be submitted to a single spreadsheet (though not to a single sheet, I think), and you can consolidate the results in the spreadsheet. You can't use `.getResponse()` efficiently because that is a `Form` cl;ass, and you have 100 forms (not a single form).

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It sounds like you are proposing to create 100 unique forms. Is that right? There is no reason why all the responses can't be submitted to a single spreadsheet (though not to a single sheet, I think), and you can consolidate the results.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. But I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: Sorry @Tanaike, "sounds like you are proposing to create 100 unique forms"-this was my comment to the OP, not to you.

Comment: @Tedinoz Oh! I'm sorry, too. Now, also I noticed that I made a mistake. I thought that the reply is from the owner of this answer.

Comment: Yes, I need to create 100 unique forms, but I can't find a way to consolidate them all in one spreadsheet without running a cronjob with .getResponse().. How do you add multiple Google Forms to each sheet in a single Spreadsheet? I am creating these forms from a script, I could not find a way to do it automatically. (no manually adding one by one to a sheet)

Comment: @Tanaike "how about linking each Google Form with a single Spreadsheet, and using the OnSubmit trigger at Spreadsheet" Yes, this would work. But how can I do it with a script? I do not want to do it manually for 100 forms.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I do not want to do it manually for 100 forms.`, in this case, it is required to know your actual situation. In your situation, you have already had those 100 Google Forms? Or,  you have never had those 100 Google Forms, and it is required to create them using a script?

Comment: I need to create them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your reply now. I apologize for this. About `I need to create them.`, in this case, it is required to know the logic for creating your 100 Google Forms. But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand the logic of it. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. So, in order to prepare a sample script, can I ask you about the detailed logic for creating the 100 Google Forms you expected? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: By the way, when you reply, when `@` is added to the user like `@username`, it will notify the user.

Comment: @Tanaike I have written the logic in my question with the extracted code. I would need to run that code as a loop for each user I have. Anyway, I think I have found the method: form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, <id>); This is how I can link automatically. Then I can find a way to consolidate from there. Much better than what I originally thought. Thank you for your answer which made me realize there is a way to automatically link a form to a sheet. I could not find it for the documentation.

Comment: @Filippo Thank you for replying. About `I have written the logic in my question with the extracted code.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your question, I couldn't understand the logic. But, from your reply, I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it. In this case, how about posting it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Related question: [How to merge a large number of form response sheets into one master sheet. (Google Sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598573/1330560) by @Rubén . An elegant solution for consolidating multiple FormResponse sheets within a single spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to consolidate all answers (aka responses) from different google forms into one spreadsheet. This can be done by adding the following code after creating the form:

```
var form = FormApp.create('Title');
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, "your gSheet ID here");
```

It will create a new sheet called "Form Responses 1",2,3,4,... for each form linked to the Spreadsheet.

Once the data is all in one spreadsheet, I can either:

- periodically loop each sheet and send the consolidated data in one single sheet
- OR, use onEdit(e), detect which sheet was edited by the form submission (e.range.getSheet()), extract the response and send the new response to a single sheet

Thanks to @tanaike for the direction